# HTTPS everywhere

Tags: discussion, feature-request, https

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can't I use https to access the stackexchange sites?](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1792/why-cant-i-use-https-to-access-the-stackexchange-sites)

I'd like to reopen the discussion about HTTPS. I'm aware it's been [asked](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1792/why-cant-i-use-https-to-access-the-stackexchange-sites) before, however I feel that it deserves to be discussed again. While the site is publicly searchable and nothing done by any user is obscured, there are people who would like to have their sessions on the SE sites encrypted. For example: one use case could be public WIFI hotspots.

Personally, I use the [EFF's plugin](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere).

edit: I was partly inspired by the developer of a site I frequent. He made it sound [annoying but doable](https://blog.theunderminejournal.com/?itemid=448).